# Return UniqueIdentifier of newly inserted row

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-insert

I have the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO [User].User_Profile

 (UniqueId, Username, EmailAddress,
  Password, BirthDay, BirthMonth,
  BirthYear, Age, AccountType, DateCreated,
  DeletedDate, DeletedReason, ProfileStatus)

  VALUES

  (NEWID(), @Username, @EmailAddress,
  @Password, @BirthDay, @BirthMonth,
  @BirthYeat, @Age, 1, SYSDATETIME(),
  null, null, 2)

  SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

The @@IDENTITY returns me the newly inserted row ID for the particular user but I need to return the NEWID() value after the insert statement has been executed as I need this NEWID() for other functionality inside the website but I'm un-certain how to retrieve it and as my SQL skills aren't great I was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: use the OUTPUT clause

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 3):

Using [OUTPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177564.aspx) clause:

```
INSERT INTO [User].User_Profile

 (UniqueId, Username, EmailAddress,
  Password, BirthDay, BirthMonth,
  BirthYear, Age, AccountType, DateCreated,
  DeletedDate, DeletedReason, ProfileStatus)

OUTPUT INSERTED.UniqueId
  VALUES

  (NEWID(), @Username, @EmailAddress,
  @Password, @BirthDay, @BirthMonth,
  @BirthYeat, @Age, 1, SYSDATETIME(),
  null, null, 2)
```

It can also be inserted into a table like this:

```
declare @output(id uniqueidentifier)
 INSERT INTO [User].User_Profile

     (UniqueId, Username, EmailAddress,
      Password, BirthDay, BirthMonth,
      BirthYear, Age, AccountType, DateCreated,
      DeletedDate, DeletedReason, ProfileStatus)

    OUTPUT INSERTED.UniqueId into @output(id)
      VALUES

      (NEWID(), @Username, @EmailAddress,
      @Password, @BirthDay, @BirthMonth,
      @BirthYeat, @Age, 1, SYSDATETIME(),
      null, null, 2)
```